# No logro agregar botón al Select2 dentro de Datatables cuando no se encuentran resultados

Tags: jquery, datatables, select2

En una de las columnas de un datatable agrego un Select2, las búsquedas se realizan satisfactoriamente, pero intento agregar un botón al final del select2 cuando no se encuentran resultados para dar la posibilidad al usuario de registrar un nuevo codificador y continuar el procesamiento. La cuestión es que no logro conformar el selector adecuado para poder hacer un append del fragmento html que dibuja el botón. Para ello aprovecho la definición del language del datatables, exactamente la etiqueta `noResults`, y tratar de agregarlo a la etiqueta `ul` cuyo `id` comienza con la cadena de texto `"select2-detalle_factura_producto_unidad_de_medida-"`; el problema con este id es que despues del guion se agregan otros caracteres aleatoriamente y por tanto el selector debe ser basado en el inicio del id.

La versión de Select2 es la 4.0.13 incluida en AdminLTE3.

```
$(_tablaDatosDetallesFacturaElement).find('select.selector-unidadmedida').select2({
                        theme: 'bootstrap4',
                        dropdownParent: $(_tablaDatosDetallesFacturaElement),
                        placeholder: 'Unidad de Medidas',
                        width: '100%',
                        minimumInputLength: 1,
                        delay: 400,
                        ajax: {
                            url: Routing.generate('unidadDeMedida_autocompletar'),
                            processResults: function (data) {
                                return data;
                            }
                        },
                        language: {
                            noResults: function () {
                             let g = $('#modalReader_contenedorForm').find('#prov').data('r');
                             console.info("llego aqui");
                             $(_tablaDatosDetallesFacturaElement).find('[id^="select2-detalle_factura_producto_unidad_de_medida-"]').append('<li class="select2-results__option"><table width="100%"><tr><td class="row"><a id="btnUnidadMedidaNuevo" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-xs' + (g === '0' ? 'disabled' : '') + ' text-secondary" data-src="' + Routing.generate('unidadDeMedida_nueva') + '" data-original-title="Registrar Unidad de Medida"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>&nbsp;Agregar nueva</a></div></td></tr></table></li>').on('click', '#btnUnidadMedidaNuevo', function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    var elemento = $(this);
                                    if (g === '0') {
                                        return false;
                                    }
    
                                    secondModalForm(elemento);
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
                            return markup;
                        }
                    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @padaleiana, muchas gracias. Arreglo en un instante!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en que al haber declarado la función `escapeMarkup(m)` en la definicion de `language` del Select2, el código html no es renderizado, además de un error al generar la url de búsqueda asociada. En resumen, la declaración de la sección del language y noResults queda de la siguiente forma:

```
language: {                        
                        noResults: function () {
                            let g = $('#modalReader_contenedorForm').find('#prov').data('r');
                            if (g === '0') {
                                return "No hay resultados";
                            }

                            $(_tablaDatosDetallesFacturaElement).find('span.select2-results > ul[id^="select2-detalle_factura_producto_unidad_de_medida-"]').append('<li class="select2-results__options"><a id="btnUnidadMedidaNuevo" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-xs' + (g === '0' ? 'disabled' : '') + ' text-secondary" data-src="' + Routing.generate('unidadDeMedida_nueva') + '" data-original-title="Registrar Unidad de Medida"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>&nbsp;Agregar nueva</a></li>').on('click', '#btnUnidadMedidaNuevo', function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                var elemento = $(this);
                                secondModalForm(elemento);
                            });

                        }
                    }
```